# rdp clients on windows with command line support

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Are there any free /commercial tool that can connect to windows server (logon using rdp) and execute a command ?

I have program that require a GUI to run. That makes testing difficult.  One way this is archived is using properrdp client(http://properjavardp.sourceforge.net/).   This accepts a usual credentials and command line program (which is batch file on the server). The tool occasionally crashes/disconnect with no apparent reason.

Some note on why:  RDP Session provide session level isolation. Application running on one session is reasonably isolated from other including mouse/keyboard actions.

I am looking for alternate tools that can do the same.

Comment: I didn't get it. You need a console to interact with the program but it also has a GUI? How does that work? Why do you specifically ask for RDP, why ain't any other technology possible? Why does the built-in solution of Windows not work, since it can also start programs? You really need Windows 2000 Support? Extended support of XP ended in 2014...

Answer (score 0):

If you enable it Windows Remote Management, [WinRM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384426(v=vs.85).aspx), then you can use WinRM scripting objects, the WinRM command-line tool, or the Windows Remote Shell command line tool WinRS which should be pre-installed on most versions of Windows.

This will allow the direct execution of power shell scripts, batch files or individual commands.

Comment: Thanks. The application require "GUI shell"..hence my need for rdp client. That way when multiple sessions are running they do not  interact.

Comment: You could automate your tests with SikuliX - http://sikulix.com/

Answer (score 0):

In the end you are going to execute a command on the target machine.

In this case why don't you just use [PowerShell](https://www.faqforge.com/windows/create-powershell-session-remote-computer/)?

Otherwise if you prefer a GUI approach you ca go for [Sikuli](http://doc.sikuli.org/tutorials/index.html).

Comment: Updated question to indicate a session isolation (also removed references to older windows version)